# Changing data types on Pandas DataFrame uploaded from CSV - mainly Object to Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime, python-object

I am working on a data frame uploaded from CSV, I have tried changing the data typed on the CSV file and to save it but it doesn't let me save it for some reason, and therefore when I upload it to Pandas the date and time columns appear as object.
I have tried a few ways to transform them to datetime but without a lot of success:

1) `df['COLUMN'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['COLUMN'].str.strip(), format='%m/%d/%Y')`
gives me the error:

> AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

2) Defining dtypes at the beginning and then using it in the `read_csv` command - gave me an error as well since it does not accept datetime but only string/int.

Some of the columns I want to have a datetime format of date, such as: 2019/1/1, and some of time: 20:00:00

Do you know of an effective way of transforming those datatype object columns to either date or time?

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe

Comment: Added it, thank you @ansev

Comment: Save it on excel and then read in pandas data frame, then you can use the date-time module? Do you think that works?

Comment: @hemanta I can't save the file as an excel file, it doesn't work

Comment: Can you share the original data? A part of it, few lines might be enough

Comment: @hemanta I downloaded it from this site: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/NYPD-Complaint-Data-Historic/qgea-i56i/data, it is the public data from NYPD

Comment: I tried to copy a few rows here but the format is messed up

Comment: Many columns have different types of data. E.g.CM_ PLTNUM  is an integer and so on. The method you used in #1 applies to all columns of the table. Can you make more clear in the question of what you really want to achieve? You said you want to convert columns in data-time? could you please make clear about this?

Comment: Download the whole data or use API. Copying might mess up your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion, I downloaded the data set from the link you provided and read it through pandas. I took one column and a part of it; which has the date and used the pandas data-time module as you did. By doing so I can use the script you mentioned.

```
#import necessary library
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#load the data into csv
data = pd.read_csv("NYPD_Complaint_Data_Historic.csv")

#take one column which contains the datatime as an example
dte = data['CMPLNT_FR_DT']

# =============================================================================
# I will try to take a part of the data from dte which contains the 
# date time and convert it to date time
# =============================================================================

from pandas import datetime
test_data  = dte[0:10]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
df1['new_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['CMPLNT_FR_DT'])
df1['year'] = [i.year for i in df1['new_col']]
df1['month'] = [i.month for i in df1['new_col']]
df1['day'] = [i.day for i in df1['new_col']]


#The way you used to convert the data also works


df1['COLUMN'] =  pd.to_datetime(df1['CMPLNT_FR_DT'].str.strip(), format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

It might be the way you get the data. You can see the output from this attached. As the result can be stored in dataframe it won't be a problem to save in any format. Please let me know if I understood correctly and it helped you. The month is not shown in the image, but you can get it.[image]